# Comma usage: City and State / Full Date

Tags: punctuation, commas

Can we eliminate the comma after "2014" and "Indiana" below? The year and state are not parenthetical, and besides, the comma slows down the flow of the sentence. I think the two sentences below are correct without those commas. Do you concur?

> The December 22, 2014 meeting has been canceled.
>
> The Gary, Indiana man was arrested on a charge of grand larceny.

Comment: There are no adjectives involved here. Those are nouns used attributively.

Comment: So comma or no comma in each?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to include all that detail in your text? My guess is that with that first sentence, if there is a need to include the exact day, you don't also need to include the year. So if I were writing it I would say either 'the 22 December meeting', or 'the December 2014 meeting'. Clearly if I am giving this information as late as November 2014, I would have used the former. But if I had been giving it back in 2012, I would simply have said 'the December 2014 meeting'.

Similarly, my guess is that you could probably get away with saying 'the Indiana man'.  In my experience many people will say they are going to 'London, England'. Now there really isn't any need to include the country because everyone knows where London is. There may be times when you will want to distinguish London, England from London, Ohio; but they are I would think, few and far between.

So my suggestion, before worrying about the punctuation is to ask yourself if you really need to include as much detail; which in my view tends to get in the way of good comprehension rather than expanding it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Canadian Style Guide](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-srch?lang=eng&srchtxt=dates&cur=2&nmbr=9&lettr=7&info0=7.20#zz7), you would need a comma after 2014 if you use month-day-year order.

You would not need a comma if you said: The meeting of 22 December 2014 was cancelled.

In the same way, a comma separates a place name from the name of a state. The name of the state should be followed by a comma in the body of a sentence.

I wouldn't say that the comma "slows down the flow of the sentence". They separate your specifications from the rest of the sentence.